# How to use native code in flutter without channeling?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, augmented-reality

I'm trying to use Ar Core and Ar Kit in my flutter application, but I don't want to use third-party packages or Channels. I want to simply open android Activity or ios ViewController to add the AR feature completely in its native way. and when the user wants to get out of the AR page, simply switch back to flutter.
is it even possible? and how can I do that?

Comment: in this way , you should integrate you flutter application inside native app

Comment: great question.